# Can I define delegate, it's instance and it's code in one line in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

Currently, to define an event hook, I am writing:

```
delegate void WinEventHookDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

...

private WinEventHookDelegate WindowEventHookInstance;

...

private void WindowEventHook(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)

...

WindowEventHookInstance = new WinEventHookDelegate(WindowEventHook);
        Install();

...

SetWinEventHook(...
                WindowEventHookInstance,     // lpfnWinEventProc
                ...);

...
```

I.e. I am creating 3 names (`WinEventHookDelegate`, `WindowEventHookInstance`, `WindowEventHook`), 2 duplicate prototype declaration and 1 assignment to get only pointer to a function.

Can I write it less redundant and shorter, maybe in one line?

Comment: Too many `...` and too little `{ }`. The crucial part, SetWinEventHook is also undefined.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it's from WinApi:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook

Answer (score 0):

You can use C#'s delegates instead of defining your own.

For delegates that point to void functions such as in your case, you can use Action.

Instead of declaring and instantiating a delegate (or in this case an Action delegate) you can stick it directly in your SetWinEventHook method like this. 
The compiler will take care of instantiation.

```
public void SetWinEventHook(Action<IntPtr, uint, IntPtr, int, int, uint, uint> myDelegate)
{

}
```

Now in order to kick off the function that your delegate points to you do this

```
myDelegate()
```

the problem, however, is that this delegate needs the 7 arguments that you declared it will need.

In order to provide that you can pass them in as a second argument in your SetWinEventHook method like this

```
 public void SetWinEventHook(Action<IntPtr, uint, IntPtr, int, int, uint, uint> myDelegate, IntPtr a, uint b, IntPtr c, int d, int e, uint f, uint g)
 {
     myDelegate(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
 }
```

So at this point you essentially

1) Declared a delegate

2) Instantiated a delegate

3) Created a hook method to kick off the delegate/function

Now all you need to do is call your SetWinEventHook and pass in either a lambda or a function written elsewhere so that your delegate will point to it.

```
     SetWinEventHook((a, b, c, d, r, f, g) => // using lambda here
     {

     },
      new IntPtr(), 1, new IntPtr(), 2,3,4,5
     );
```